# Is there a specific Google OAuth v2 Refresh Token URL?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I created a google console project and it provided all the necessary credentials as such....

```
{  
   "web":{  
      "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "client_id":"1234567890example.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "client_secret":"1234567890abcexample",
      "project_id":"abc123example",
      "javascript_origins":[  
         "https://zapier.com"
      ]
   }
}
```

...except for a refresh_token_url. Using the provided credentials I can successfully setup static OAuth2, but it stops working after the initial token expires.

All I need is Google's refresh_token_url (if they have one) to plugin and I should be good to go. I already tried using the same /token url in the refresh URL and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The refresh token endpoing is the token auth_uri

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

You can also check the [discovery document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#discovery)

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will definitely check this out.